# Check if the user posted comment on a post

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I check if the visitor who is currently reading a post has written a comment on that post?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com might be worth a go to get a good answer to this question, if you don't get a decent answer here =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no 100% way to do this, but the best way would be to set a cookie with the ID of the post that they commented on, and check that when they visit.  There just might be a Wordpress plugin that does that already, but I don't know for sure;  Google it.